# SQL Syntax Error - Two Column Inner Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am attempting to get a SQL query working (in Access 2007), but I am repeatedly getting a generic error message about a syntax error, that simply states (not typoed - it seems to truncate the SQL):

```
Syntax error in query expression 'Metric.ID = Metric_Value_Measurement.Metric_ID AND (SELECT Measurement_Date FROM Metric_Value_Measurement WHERE Metric_ID = '1') = Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Dat'.
```

The SQL I am attempting to use is below - I have checked that the `SELECT` query that is nested works as expeted outside this query, and if I remove the `AND` section from the `INNER JOIN`, the rest of the query works as expected.

Can anyone suggest where my syntax may be wrong?

```
SELECT Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
,Metric.Description
,Metric.Unit
,Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date
FROM (
(
    Metric INNER JOIN Desired_Future_State_Metric 
            ON Metric.ID = Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
    ) INNER JOIN Metric_Unitvalue ON Metric.ID = Metric_Unitvalue.Metric_ID
)
INNER JOIN Metric_Value_Measurement ON (
    Metric.ID = Metric_Value_Measurement.Metric_ID
    AND (
        SELECT MAX(Measurement_Date)
        FROM Metric_Value_Measurement
        WHERE Metric_ID = Metric.ID
        ) = Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date
    )
GROUP BY Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
,Metric.Description
,Metric.Unit
,Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date;
```

EDIT: With thanks to David Wallace below, it appears that the issue is that I am comparing a single value `Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date` with multiple values; this was an oversight in adding my code here, as the `SELECT` statement should have read `SELECT MAX(Measurement_Date)` to get the most recent date for a given record. Having modified this, I still get a syntax error (same error as before). Is there something else I need to do in order to join these tables?

EDIT 2: As None of the answers so far seem to have resolved the issue, I thought it might be useful to post the structure of the relevant tables:

```
Metric
----------
ID
Description

Desired_Future_State_Metric
----------
ID
Metric_ID
Desired_Future_State_ID
Target_Value
Target_Date

Metric_Value_Measurement
----------
ID
Metric_ID
Measurement_Date
Measurement_Value
```

The goal is to get the most recent `Measurement_Value` for a given `Metric_ID` - as the code below doesn't seem to work, I'm open to suggestions as to how I would get this. In summary, the value I'm looking for is the first `Measurement_Value` for a given `Metric_ID`, when the list is ordered by date descending.

Comment: I have added the structure of the tables, in the hope that someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a syntax error in your SQL, although there could be a problem if you have multiple rows in `Metric_Value_Measurement` with the same `Metric_ID` but different `Measurement_Date` values.

However, your SQL is FAR too complicated for what you're doing.  Assuming that you don't have multiple rows in `Metric_Value_Measurement` with the same `Metric_ID` but different `Measurement_Date` values, your SQL is actually equivalent to this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
,Metric.Description
,Metric.Unit
,Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date
FROM Metric 
JOIN Desired_Future_State_Metric ON Metric.ID = Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
JOIN Metric_Unitvalue ON Metric.ID = Metric_Unitvalue.Metric_ID
JOIN Metric_Value_Measurement ON Metric.ID = Metric_Value_Measurement.Metric_ID
```

**EDIT**

OK, now that you've added the `MAX()` in there, you've got a clause in your join that should really be part of a `WHERE` clause, not part of a `JOIN`.  So add this additional part after all the `JOIN` clauses.

```
WHERE Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date = (
    SELECT MAX(Measurement_Date)
    FROM Metric_Value_Measurement
    WHERE Metric_ID = Metric.ID )
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is possible to have multiple records in Metric_Value_Measurement with the same Metric_ID, but different dates - the use case is that this table records measurement values over time for various different metrics.

Comment: Then that is your problem with the original SQL.  You've got a subquery that could have multiple values, and you're comparing it to a single value.  That's an error in any sort of SQL, but technically not a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks David - Unfortunately this was an error in my code, which should have had a MAX() clause in the SELECT, to return only the most recent date for a given Metric_ID. Unfortunately this has not solved the problem, however (same error).

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to:

1. Pull each ID in Metric but only for the lasest measurements? OR
2. Pull only those IDs that have the max measurement date?

I think you are aiming for the first, but your code seems to be implementing the second.  In any case, I think the key to either case is to pull the AND portion of your last INNER JOIN.

In the first case, you can save this as as separate query, say qryMeasurement_Date_Maxs:

```
SELECT Metric_ID, MAX(Measurement_Date) AS Measurement_Date_Max
FROM Metric_Value_Measurement
```

And change your main query to:

```
SELECT Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
,Metric.Description
,Metric.Unit
,Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date
FROM (
(
    Metric INNER JOIN Desired_Future_State_Metric 
            ON Metric.ID = Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
    ) INNER JOIN Metric_Unitvalue ON Metric.ID = Metric_Unitvalue.Metric_ID
)
INNER JOIN Metric_Value_Measurement ON (
    Metric.ID = Metric_Value_Measurement.Metric_ID
    )
INNER JOIN qryMeasurement_Date_Maxs ON (
    Metric_Value_Measurement.Metric_ID = qryMeasurement_Date_Maxs.Metric_ID
    AND Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date = qryMeasurement_Date_Maxs.Measurement_Date_Max
)
GROUP BY Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
,Metric.Description
,Metric.Unit
,Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date;
```

In the second case, I think you can shift the max date in a HAVING predicate:

```
SELECT Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
,Metric.Description
,Metric.Unit
,Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date
FROM (
(
    Metric INNER JOIN Desired_Future_State_Metric 
            ON Metric.ID = Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
    ) INNER JOIN Metric_Unitvalue ON Metric.ID = Metric_Unitvalue.Metric_ID
)
INNER JOIN Metric_Value_Measurement ON (
    Metric.ID = Metric_Value_Measurement.Metric_ID
    )
GROUP BY Desired_Future_State_Metric.Desired_Future_State_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Metric_ID
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Value
,Desired_Future_State_Metric.Target_Date
,Metric.Description
,Metric.Unit
,Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date
HAVING Metric_Value_Measurement.Measurement_Date = DMax("Measurement_Date", "Metric_Value_Measurement");
```

I think one of the two is what you're looking for.  If not, hopefully can give you more ideas to play with.

Comment: Just took a look this morning again and I take back what I said about your code implementing the second scenario.  I see what you are trying to do with Metric.ID = Metric.ID in the AND part of the INNER JOIN.  I don't know if Access' db engine likes a row-by-row lookup in the INNER JOIN.  Don't think I've ever done that before.  But looking now, I know what you were getting at.  Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Access require to have parentheses around every join used, but I could see the missing one

```
ON (
    Metric_tab.ID = Metric_Value_Measurement.Metric_ID
```

Can you please place a closing parentheses around this one and further change the placement of parentheses accordingly?

Comment: As I said in the question, if I remove AND section from the inner join, the query works - as such, I don't think there are any missing parentheses. Also, there is no section of the code that refers to `Metric_tab.ID` so I'm not sure which area you are looking at?

Comment: I could see the missing parentheses around Metric.ID = Metric_Value_Measurement.Metric_ID, it is not missing but it has to be closed

Comment: It is closed, if you look at the very bottom of the statement.

Comment: I'm talking about the JOIN before AND, it has to be closed before "AND"

Comment: Closing the bracket before AND doesn't make sense - the bracket is needed to enclose the entire "ON" clause; closing it before AND still results in a syntax error.